# Function vs Function() in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, types

What is the difference between type specifying a variable as **Function** vs **Function()**.

When I declare a variable as

```dart
final Function? btnOkOnPress;
```

And then use/call it like this

```dart
btnOkOnPress?.call();
```

I get a warning/problem saying, `Avoid method calls or property accesses on a "dynamic" target.`

But when I declare it like

```dart
final Function()? btnOkOnPress;
```

There is no such warning, why is that?

Why is it calling target as `dynamic` even though it is defined as `Function`.

Comment: `function` is a variable, and `function()` you are calling the actual precess.  Can you include more about your use cases, where and how you are putting theses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warnings are because when you declare it this way
`final Function? btnOkOnPress;` the details of the parameters to the function is not given.

And when you declare in the other way, it is being specified that there is no parameters for this function.
You could also use `final VoidCallback? btnOkOnPress;`.